# Does a subscriber node in pglogical "pull", or are updates "pushed"?

Tags: postgresql

I've configured a simple pglogical replication between two nodes.

What I've not found yet is if the subscriber node pulls data, or if the publisher node initiates a push of data.

I'm intending to have geographically distributed nodes behind firewalls, which at this stage (without doing something like a VPN) would mean I have to have the subscribers pull data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscribers initiate the TCP connection to the publisher.

Comment: Do you have a link where this is described, or where it can be seen in the code?

Comment: Not explicitly, but since the subscriber is given the publishers hostname/IP and port (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createsubscription.html), while the publisher doesn't have that info about the subscriber, it is the only way it can work.